# Most Pythonic Condition Counter

Tags: python

I have a list, and need to create a count of how many times a condition is met.  Is it more pythonic to do this:

```
cnt = sum([1 for s in a_list if some_condition])
```

or is this more pythonic:

```
cnt = 0
  for s in a_list:
    if (some_condition):
      cnt += 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the fact, that `True` used as an integer is `1`:

```
cnt = sum(some_condition(s) for s in a_list)
```

Comment: This adds a lot of overhead if `some_condition` isn't already a function you need to call.

Comment: no overhead, `some_condition` can be any expression, e.g. `s > 4`, so it can be faster than DeepSpace's answer.

Answer (score 15):

Neither.

Use the first one but without creating an unnecessary list in memory:

`cnt = sum(1 for s in a_list if some_condition)`

Comment: Very cool; I didn't know about this kind of list comprehension functionality without actually creating the list.  What is this called?

Comment: @Dr.Drew Generator Expression: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/

Comment: Very nice answer!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it more simply:

```
cnt = sum(map(condition_func, a_list))
```

That assumes condition_func is some sort of function that turns an item in the list into True or False.

Comment: It's important to note that if `condition_func` is not a built-in then the performance of `map` might be worse than some of the other alternatives.

Comment: @DeepSpace: Do you think `map()` would be worse than Daniel's otherwise equivalent answer?

Comment: @DeepSpace could you elaborate a little on that? (or give some reference at least). 
JohnZwinck - really like the answer (and actually use that kind of things a lot), but summing "True" or "False" values isn't very clear pattern (I've seen a lot of questions here on SO regarding such things).

Comment: Sorry for the mixup, `map` becomes slower when used with lambdas. It's alright as long as the function remains the same every iteration. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1247490/1453822

Comment: It's not just `lambda`; the `lambda` expression isn't re-evaluted for each object.

Comment: Unless you already have a function that accepts the right argument(s), you need to provide a user-defined wrapper function as the first argument of `map`. It's the overhead of calling the wrapper that can make a `map`-based solution slower than an alternative.